# Best Practices to Start/Stop Youtube iFrames with Zurb Foundation Reveal.js

Tags: jquery, youtube, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, autoplay

This question has been asked many times but is rarely answered in full. Since it seems to be such a common UI issue I'm wondering if anyone can chime in on the best way to accomplish Youtube Videos/Vimeo Videos in modals(in this case, specifically with Reveal) that autoplay on open and stop on close.

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours finding solutions that had significant bugs when introducing template parts where the same modal repeated on different pages or when introducing multiple modals I decided to combine the common methods I was seeing. This now works but I would love to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
<html>

<a data-toggle="exampleModal8">

<div class="full reveal" id="exampleModal8" data-reveal>
    <div id="player">

    </div>

      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close 
reveal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
</html>

  <script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'YOURID GOES HERE; the numbers AFTER https://www.youtube.com/embed/',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.stopVideo();
// I changed the event.target above from startVideo to stopVideo. When the player is ready I don't want it to start until I open reveal. But not sure if this is the best way to do it?
  }


  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
 // I DELETED THEIR CODE HERE IN THE SAMPLE TO STOP THE VIDEO AFTER 6 SECONDS AS SHOWN IN THE EXAMPLE 
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
<script>
 // This tells the Youtube Video to start and stop respectively when reveal opens or closes. Note that Foundation 6 has a new way to bind these events so make sure you're not using outdated JS from older version!
$(document).on('closed.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
 player.stopVideo();
});
$(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
player.playVideo();
});
</script>
```